# front end validation failed that caused loss of correct value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using spring web flow 2.4.0 and primefaces 5.0. I found that when there is a failure in front end primefaces validation, e.g. number format. It will trigger some correct values lost in the same form id. It has not trigger any function in the web flow and I have not assigned null values to these correct values.

I have been tried to solve but failed. Do you have any hints or solutions?? Please help.

Note: It happened in selectmanycheckbox with selectedvalue that the itemsdisable is true. If I remove itemDisabled.... attribute, it will not have problem But the checkbox is enabled

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1" > 
   <p:selectManyCheckbox layout="grid" id="gridTeacherName" 
             value="#{teacherList.selectTeachers.selectedValue}" >      
      <f:selectItems itemLabelEscaped="false" 
          value="#{teacherList.selectTeachers.filterTeacherNameList}"
             var="teacher" 
           itemDisabled=   
           "#teacherList.selectTeachers.disableCheckBox(teacher.timRefNo)}" 
                itemLabel="#{teacher.getisServingMoreThanOneSchool()}" 
             itemValue="#  {teacher.timRefNo}" /> 
   </p:selectManyCheckbox> 
</p:panelGrid>
```

//------------------------POPUP Form with tabView------------------//

```
<p:dialog id="dialogEsscp2s3" widgetVar="dialogEsscp2s3" width="70vw"  
    rendered="true" modal="true" draggable="true" position="center" 
        resizable="false" header="#{esLabel['lbl.esscp2s1']}"  closeOnEscape="true"
        onHide="PF('dialogEsscp2s3').content.empty();closePopUp()"> 
        <p:remoteCommand id="closePopUp" name="closePopUp" action="cancel" process="@this" />

        <p:outputPanel id="panelEsscp2s3" rendered="false" >

            <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="height: 600px;">            
             <p:messages escape="false"  id="dialogMessages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
            <p:tabView id="tabView2s3" styleClass="ui-edb-noneborder-grid" activeIndex="#{activeTabViewIndex}" style="border:none">
                <p:tab id="tab2s3a1" title="#{esLabel['lbl.esscp2s3.lbl.Course']}" disabled="#{disableFirstTab}">

                    .......................
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="tab2s3a2" title="#{esLabel['lbl.esscp2s3.lbl.Participants']}" disabled="#{disableSecondTab}">

                        <ui:include src="esscp2s4-popup-participants.xhtml"/>
                    <!-- here has the <p:selectManyCheckbox/> controls -->
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>

            </p:scrollPanel>
        </p:outputPanel>
 </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by moving front end validation to backend controller validation. and use below code when validation failed to reassign the correct values.

```
if(isinvalid){
            dtWebVoEsccp2s3.setInvalid(true);
dtWebVoEsccp2s3.getAttendantList().getSelectTeachers().setSelectedValue(selectedValue);
        context.getFlowScope().put("teacherList", dtWebVoEsccp2s3.getAttendantList());
            return false;
        }
```